# Load up previously saved NER models in SpaCy v1.1.2

Tags: python, spacy

So whenever I try to load up a previously saved model for SpaCy NER, I get a core dump.

```
if os.path.isfile( model_path ):
    ner.model.load( model_path )
for itn in range( 5 ):
    random.shuffle( TRAIN_DATA )
    for raw_text, entity_offsets in TRAIN_DATA:
        doc = nlp.make_doc( raw_text )
        gold = GoldParse( doc, entities=entity_offsets )
        ner.update( doc, gold ) # <- Core dump occurs here
```

Dump report:

```
7fb1b7459000-7fb1b7499000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [1]    23967 abort (core dumped)
```

Am I doing/loading it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Turns out I don't need to load the model in order to update it, all I need to do is remove

```
if os.path.isfile( model_path ):
    ner.model.load( model_path )
```

And add

```
ner.model.dump( model_path )
```

to the end like so:

```
for itn in range( 5 ):
random.shuffle( TRAIN_DATA )
for raw_text, entity_offsets in TRAIN_DATA:
    doc = nlp.make_doc( raw_text )
    gold = GoldParse( doc, entities=entity_offsets )
    ner.update( doc, gold ) 
ner.model.dump( model_path )
```

in order for it to append to the previously saved data. All good!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. There's probably still a bug here, though. Obviously you should be able to write to a pre-loaded model!

Comment: Thats what I thought too, but it apparently its appending to the file?