# Does calling `ner.update()` multiple times makes any difference?

Tags: named-entity-recognition, spacy

I am trying to understand how to add entity classes to the Named Entity Recognizer. An [example code](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/entity-recognition#updating) has a structure that looks like:

```
ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab, entity_types=[... ENTITIES ...])
for itn in range(NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS):
    for raw_text, entities in training_examples:
        ... some data handling ...
        ner.update(doc, gold)
```

, but then the next example (for BILUO tags) calls `ner.update()` only once (i.e., no for-loops that cause `update()` to see the training data multiple times).

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209882/load-up-previously-saved-ner-models-in-spacy-v1-1-2), whose answers seem to tell me I *should* call `update()` more than once for each training example; but then I also thought they could be just following the examples.

Because of the following sentence (from the end of the documentation page)...

> The costs are then used to calculate the gradient of the loss, to train the model.

... I am guessing that the answer to my question is "yes, I should train it by iterating 'several' times through the training data"; but if that is the case, then does anyone have suggestion on how many times is "enough"? (the example code uses 5, but if I think it is too less, can I end up iterating "too many times"? I.e., does it "overfit"?)

Comment: (I tried looking at the code. Not sure what it is doing. There seems to be some state machine. Based on that sentence, I am obviously guessing it uses some gradient descent, but I can't tell the relation between that state machine and the gradients. I am hoping asking here will be easier than having to decipher the details myself)

Comment: Ohh... if I understood right, the Entity Recognizer uses the `thinc` AveragedPerceptron for classification. I don't get the details yet, but I am guessing that, yes, definitely, it is some (possibly overfittable) gradient descent.